# Deleting data of specific hour range mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to delete data from a table based on the hour of the datetime.

The datetime column is in standard MySQL format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`), and I want to delete any data where the hour is greater than 3 and less than 23.

Comment: Try writing some SQL and solving the problem first. If you start getting errors back or unexpected results, use that information to ask a more specific question.

Comment: [MySQL: "Extract part of a date"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the HOUR() function that SQL offers, and use the BETWEEN operator in your where statement.

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE HOUR(dateColumn) BETWEEN 4 AND 22
```

You want the values to be 4 and 22 here because in mysql BETWEEN is inclusive, and your question stated you did not want values 3 or 23.

[Here are some more Date/Time functions for you.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)